# Change background color of image in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

How to change background color of a  tag in svg.
I have a transparent image loaded in image tag now i want to apply background to apply shade with color picker.

```
<svg width="200" height="200"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">       
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="200" width="200"/>
</svg>
```

Background of svg is changing but not serving my puspose. i want to apply color direct on image tag

Answer (score 0):

In your css file, you can simply add

```
svg {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

Watch out, this will be applied to *all* svg elements in your document, to avoid this you should use a class or an id.

Alternatively, you can add it directly into your element, if for some reason you cannot modify your css file:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background-color: rebeccapurple">       
    <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="200" width="200"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Background of svg is changing but not serving my puspose. i want to apply color direct on image tag

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css to change background color of either body or the svg/image?

```
svg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
body {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Background of svg is changing but not serving my puspose. i want to apply color direct on image tag

Answer (score 0):

With the mask property, you create a mask that is applied to an element. Everywhere the mask is opaque, or solid, the underlying image shows through. Where it’s transparent, the underlying image is masked out or hidden.

```
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(icon.svg);
    mask-image: url(icon.svg);
```